# Read the next word in a file in python

Tags: python

I am looking for some words in a file in python. After I find each word I need to read the next two words from the file. I've looked for some solution but I could not find reading just the next words.

```
# offsetFile - file pointer
# searchTerms - list of words

for line in offsetFile:
    for word in searchTerms:
        if word in line:
           # here get the next two terms after the word
```

Thank you for your time.

Update: Only the first appearance is necessary. Actually only one appearance of the word is possible in this case.

file:

```
accept 42 2820 access 183 3145 accid 1 4589 algebra 153 16272 algem 4 17439 algol 202 6530
```

word: ['access', 'algebra']

Searching the file when I encounter 'access' and 'algebra', I need the values of 183 3145 and 153 16272 respectively.

Comment: You should post an example of what your file looks like.

Comment: for your last comment, do you mean the next two words after the word you found in the line? Could you provide some sample input/output?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

An easy way to deal with this is to read the file using a generator that yields one word at a time from the file.

```
def words(fileobj):
    for line in fileobj:
        for word in line.split():
            yield word
```

Then to find the word you're interested in and read the next two words:

```
with open("offsetfile.txt") as wordfile:
    wordgen = words(wordfile)
    for word in wordgen:
        if word in searchterms:   # searchterms should be a set() to make this fast
            break
    else:
        word = None               # makes sure word is None if the word wasn't found

    foundwords = [word, next(wordgen, None), next(wordgen, None)]
```

Now `foundwords[0]` is the word you found, `foundwords[1]` is the word after that, and `foundwords[2]` is the second word after it.  If there aren't enough words, then one or more elements of the list will be `None`.

It is a little more complex if you want to *force* this to match only within one line, but usually you can get away with considering the file as just a sequence of words.

Comment: I think this is right, but the asker should specify whether he's looking for only the first appearance of the word or multiple appearances

Comment: Yes, you need an additional loop to keep going if you want to find multiple occurrences. That's easy to add.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I've made some slight changes and its working perfectly: line = line.split(" ")

Comment: What if the file contains one big line, without any newline character? I want to avoid reading the entire file for just one word.

Comment: You'd have to read it in smaller chunks and split it up. `file.read()` takes a maximum number of bytes to read; you could read, say, 16K max, split it, yield each word from the list, etc. The only trick is that the last word might be partial; you'd need to detect that and handle it specially.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to retrieve only two first words, just do it:

```
offsetFile.readline().split()[:2]
```

Comment: "next two terms after the [search] word"

Answer (score 1):

```
word = '3' #Your word
delim = ',' #Your delim

with open('test_file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if word in line:
            s_line = line.strip().split(delim)
            two_words = (s_line[s_line.index(word) + 1],\
            s_line[s_line.index(word) + 2])
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    def searchTerm(offsetFile, searchTerms):
            # remove any found words from this list; if empty we can exit
            searchThese = searchTerms[:]
            for line in offsetFile:
                    words_in_line = line.split()
                    # Use this list comprehension if always two numbers continue a word.
                    # Else use words_in_line.
                    for word in [w for i, w in enumerate(words_in_line) if i % 3 == 0]:
                            # No more words to search.
                            if not searchThese:
                                    return
                            # Search remaining words.
                            if word in searchThese:
                                    searchThese.remove(word)
                                    i = words_in_line.index(word)
                                    print words_in_line[i:i+3]
```

For 'access', 'algebra' I get this result:

['access', '183', '3145']
['algebra', '153', '16272']